# SQLite3 syntax error trying to create foreign key

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to create a bunch of tables in sqlite3 and I am getting an error that I can't fix. Something to do with my syntax for sqlite3 for foreign keys but can't figure it out.

```
CREATE TABLE students (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(64),
last_name VARCHAR(64)
 );


CREATE TABLE classes (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
class_name VARCHAR(64)
);



CREATE TABLE students_classes (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 students_id INTEGER,
 classes_id INTEGER,
 FOREIGN KEY (students_id) REFERENCES students(id),
 FOREIGN KEY (classes_id) REFERENCES classes(id)
);



CREATE TABLE teachers (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 classes_id INTEGER,
 first_name VARCHAR(64),
 last_name VARCHAR(64),
 FOREIGN KEY classes_id REFERENCES classes(id)
);


CREATE TABLE grades (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 students_id INTEGER,
 grade_num INTEGER,
 FOREIGN KEY students_id REFERENCES students(id)
 );


 Error: near "students_id": syntax error
```

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (students_id)` - try with `(` and `)`.

Comment: @PM77-1 has the answer.  Perhaps they should add it as such.

Comment: @PM77-1 could you explain a little bit more?  Are you saying add a double set of parenthesis or add an AND in between them?  Sorry i'm a newbie.

Comment: Add parenthesis. Not certain if this would help.

Comment: I figured it out, it was written like FOREIGN KEY (students_id) when it should have been FOREIGN KEY(students_id) with no space

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite Docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) seem to indicate that column name(s) in `FOREIGN Key` constraint must be inside parenthesis:

[image: table constrint diagram]

I'm not sure how strictly it's actually enforced.  My [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/62495) shows that using parenthesis should solve your problem.

Please note that `SQL Fiddle` for `SQLite` is **emulated**, so your result might still vary.

Comment: Why are you not sure how strictly it is enforced? This entire question is about the strict enforcement. And sqlite.js is a straight C-to-JavaScript translation.

Comment: @CL - I ran it on `WebSQL`. My point was - using proper syntax would never hurt, though *sometimes* you *might* be able to get away with less.

Comment: WebSQL uses the native SQLite library in the browser.

Comment: @CL OK. Not being an expert is `SQLite3` I afforded myself some uncertainty. I do not believe OP (or any future onlookers) will suffer because of that.